# Error in the app at launching a phone call

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, xcode7, phone-call

I'm working on a app in which you can make an phone call after touch the label with the number. But at the moment in which the phone call is done, the Xcode Log shows me a log of error with the constraints..

I thought that was because the custom navigation controller on my app, but even with de default nav controller shows me the log.

I don't know what I should do and where is the error. Even with this Storyboards shown below, the log remains..

Story with custom nav controller
[image: App with custom Navigation Controller]

Story with default nav controller
[image: App with default Navigation Controller]

This is the log..

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try
>   this:         (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect;         (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint
>   or constraints and fix it.  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" ) Will attempt to recover by
>   breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2016-05-18 17:11:25.093
>   App[742:295497] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
>   the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The log should list the constraints that are in conflict. Deciphering that information is hard, but it's what you have to do to figure out what's going on. If you can't figure it out, edit your question to include the list of constraints that are conflicting. I'm not very good at deciphering that stuff, but others can likely help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check every connection from de UI builder to the code. That's always the case for my when that happens.